# VueJS - How to unset a data property that is bound to an element hidden with v-if?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, data-binding

I need some help with destroying/unsetting some data properties in VueJS when such properties are bound to DOM elements hidden with a v-if.

I have a real-world scenario, but, for the purpose of this post, I'll stick with a simple example.

In my HTML I have the following:

```
<html><body>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="myFields.SelectedValue">
  <option disabled value="">Choose a Programming language</option>
  <option>PHP</option>
  <option>Python</option>
  <option>C#</option>
</select>

<input v-if="myFields.SelectedValue == 'PHP'" type="text" label="Your favorite version of PHP" v-model="myFields.favPHP">

<br>
<pre>
{{myFields}}  
</pre>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And on JavaScript, I got this:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myFields:{
        SelectedValue: ''
    }
  }
})
```

When I select the option "PHP" in the select field, VueJS renders the input field, as expected. Then I can type anything and the value will be bound to the property `myFields.favPHP`.
The problem is: If I decide to change my option in the select field for, say, "Python", the text input field will be removed, as it must be, but the `myFields.favPHP` is not unset.
I don't think there's a native way of achieving this and I have no idea about what can I do to solve this.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bneeer/5jumo3aq/1/

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `v-on:change` event handler which deletes the unnecessary value.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myFields: {
      SelectedValue: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="myFields.SelectedValue" v-on:change='delete myFields.favPHP'>
    <option disabled value="">Choose a Programming language</option>
    <option>PHP</option>
    <option>Python</option>
    <option>C#</option>
  </select>

  <input v-if="myFields.SelectedValue == 'PHP'" type="text" label="Your favorite version of PHP" v-model="myFields.favPHP">

  <br>
  <pre>
{{myFields}}  
</pre>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Native way to destroy property sure exist in JavaScript, it's called delete operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete.

Your JS part would look like something:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    myFields:{
        SelectedValue: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deleteFavPhpField($event) {
        if($event.target.value !== 'PHP')
      delete this.myFields.favPHP;
    }
  }
})
```

And in HTML part you would add `input` trigger on select element, like this:

`<select v-model="myFields.SelectedValue" @change="deleteFavPhpField($event)">`

But I would suggest another approach since `delete` operator isn't something that should be used easily. You can have you `myFields.favPHP` field sett in data from beggining, and in `<pre>` element you could display computed value, out of `newFields` but without `favPHP` if it's empty. For example, you computed could be something like this:

```
computed: {
  formattedFields() {
    if(this.myFields.favPHP) return { ...this.myFields };
    return {SelectedValue: this.myFields.SelectedValue}; // here you can use some iterator if you have more fields
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach! I tried the other solution (delete) and it worked, of course, but I got your point, something in my project code still doesn't seem right. I'll try your suggestion as soon as I can